# SQL Joins issue oracle 11g

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

Can someone show me what Im doing wrong?

**The Question:**

Create a unique list of first and last names for anyone living at 4389 Jaffa Terrace S.

**The ERD:**

[image]

**What Ive Tried:**

```
SQL> SELECT MORTAL.FIRST_NAME, MORTAL.LAST_NAME
  2  FROM MORTAL
  3  LEFT JOIN MORTAL_ADDRESS ON MORTAL.MORTAL_ID = MORTAL_ADDRESS.MORTAL_ID
  4  LEFT JOIN ADDRESS ON MORTAL_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID
  5  WHERE ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE1 LIKE '4389%';

no rows selected
```

I don't really like the 'LIKE' operator, I would rather use an '=' instead.

```
    SQL> SELECT MORTAL.FIRST_NAME, MORTAL.LAST_NAME
  2  FROM MORTAL
  3  LEFT JOIN MORTAL_ADDRESS ON MORTAL.MORTAL_ID = MORTAL_ADDRESS.MORTAL_ID
  4  LEFT JOIN ADDRESS ON MORTAL_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID
  5  WHERE ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE1 = '4389%';

no rows selected

SQL> SELECT MORTAL.FIRST_NAME, MORTAL.LAST_NAME
  2  FROM MORTAL
  3  LEFT OUTER JOIN MORTAL_ADDRESS ON MORTAL.MORTAL_ID = MORTAL_ADDRESS.MORTAL_ID
  4  LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS ON MORTAL_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID
  5  WHERE ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE1 = '4389%';

no rows selected
```

I know it's in the joins somewhere, but this seems like a straight forward left join, as by this Ive seen, on w3schools.com:

[image]

Ive run a couple queries to test the data:

```
SQL> select address_line1 from address
  2  where upper(substr(address_line1, 5,1)) = 'J';

no rows selected

SQL> select address_line1 from address
  2  where address_line1 like '4389%';

ADDRESS_LINE1
-------------------------------------------------------
4389 JAFFA Terrace S.
4389 Jaffa Terrace S.
```

Is there a way to do this, that I haven't seen, without using 'LIKE' ?

(please answer as an answer, not a comment, so I can up-tick you. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MORTAL.FIRST_NAME, MORTAL.LAST_NAME
FROM MORTAL
JOIN MORTAL_ADDRESS ON MORTAL.MORTAL_ID = MORTAL_ADDRESS.MORTAL_ID
JOIN ADDRESS ON MORTAL_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID = ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID
WHERE ADDRESS.ADDRESS_LINE1 LIKE '%4389%';
```

Try it like this, if it works you need a TRIM on that column.

Probably the address is spread around

```
WHERE zip_code=4389 AND ADDRESS_LINE1='Jaffa...'
```

Comment: I still get 'no rows selected'.

Comment: @BrianWilson Are you sure there is data in that column?

Comment: yes, the data is in that column:
4389 JAFFA Terrace S.

4389 Jaffa Terrace S.
@Mihai

Comment: @BrianWilson Try it with inner join.

Comment: ok, figured it out, 'no rows selected' is the correct answer. Turns out My cert instructor tried to sneak one in. The address id for that address in address table, doesn't exist in the mortal_address table. So basically its a dead record.